# Draw a graph with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I found a graph in Wikimedia collection of graphs made using gnuplot. Its URL is https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Gnuplot_diagrams#/media/File:Boucle_comby_paris_2011.svg . It was done by Gandie - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=16938702 . There are two lines composed of data points in the graph. The only method I am capable of performing now to create such graph is to draw two graphs with gnuplot first where there is one line in each graph and then use photoshop to merge them into one graph. However, I am going to draw a graph in which around one hundred lines are composed of data points. I have to integrate the whole process in gnuplot because handling one hundred graphs in photoshop is pretty painful to me. If you can provide any advice about writing a gunplot script for such task, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In gnuplot, you draw a plot with the 'plot' command and specify a data set and how to draw the line.  In order to draw multiple lines, simply put a comma and then specify another data set and options.

I do this often with data showing how my students performed on an exam, compared to other semesters:

> plot 'S19_Exam1.csv' using 2:3 with linespoints lw 2 title 'S19 Exam 1', 'S18_Exam1.csv' using 2:3 with ...,
>   'S17_Exam1.csv' using 2:3 with ...,

In your case, you'll have 100 data specification lines, each separated by a comma.